# SSH Private Key in PuTTY Not Working

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, security, putty

I have read through every StackExchange Q/A I could find regarding SSH failing with key pairs from PuTTY. I generated an RSA key pair using `ssh-keygen` on macOS, used `ssh-copy-id` to copy the public key to the `authorized_keys` file on my server, and after disabling password authentication I was able to login to the server with the key pair successfully.

I then went over to my Windows PC, opened up PuTTYGen, imported the id_rsa (private key) file, and saved the private key to the `ppk` format. Yet, when I added this to my PuTTY>Connection>SSH>Auth>Priv.Key and tried logging into my server, I get `server refused our key` from the console window.

I have tried changing the number of bits from 2048 to 4096 in the PuTTYGen window (since the fingerprint says ssh-rsa 4096), I checked the permissions on the `authorized_keys` file (600) & its directory (700), used KiTTY and Solar PuTTY as alternatives, and changed the log level to `DEBUG3` in the server's `sshd_config`. After the last, I noticed this:

```
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug2: key not found
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: key 0x559259bd7e00 is not allowed
Failed publickey for root from 10.0.0.125 port 57253 ssh2: RSA SHA256:...
```

Honestly, I'm just at a loss for what to try next. I feel like I've tried everything, but I also don't know if I just don't understand the debug logs well enough. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "I have tried changing the number of bits..." The number of bits is a property of the key which you're converting. You can't just change that while converting the key to a different file format. You might be generating a new key in puttygen rather than converting the old key.

Comment: The *"Parameters"* section on the bottom on the PuTTYgen window has any effect only if you *"Generate"* new key. It has no effect (and the values are not even relevant to the key), when you are converting an existing key only.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the Putty using SSH private key converted to Putty format but server refusing to use it.
My solution was:

1. Download latest putty and puttygen: e.g. 0.76 from [www.chiark.greenend.org.uk](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)
2. Regenerate Putty private key using updated puttygen
3. Repeat login using latest putty configured to use the regenerated private key

For the private key conversion/export I used the default puttygen settings.
The new putty private key ended up with the following header:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-3: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: imported-openssh-key
Public-Lines: 6
```

Hope this helps